# How to use Segoe Print font in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to make my webpage use the font Segoe Print, which is not a default browser font. I have the ttf file though, is there any way I can employ this .ttf file so that every visitor (no matter what browser) can see the font ?

I searched and found some solutions, one was saying "Convert the font using [this site](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)"
but it gives the error:

> Microsoft has requested that their font Segoe Print to be blacklisted
> by the generator

So how can I use this font on my website ?

I also found a solution that suggests the following CSS rule :

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('Segoe.ttf'),
     url('Segoe.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

But, will it work in non-windows browsers? I mean, does the user have to have the ttf file in their computer, or will it be loaded from my website ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Kirsle](http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi) to convert your TTF font to EOT. Then you need to import three format of your font in the top of your CSS, with this format:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe’;
    src:url('fonts/Segoe.eot?#’) format(‘eot’),    
        url(‘fonts/Segoe.woff’) format(‘woff’); 
        url(‘fonts/Segoe.ttf’) format(‘truetype’);  
}
```

Remeber to have the ?#, it will deceive the IE to only see the first line and download it, as other browsers can't see the first line and will download the TTF format & New browsers will download the WOFF that have a less size, so will download faster.

Simply use `font-family: Segoe` to change an item's font in your CSS.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot, in any legal and morally acceptable way. It would be illegal and morally wrong to give advice on committing the crime that such unauthorized use would constitute.

You should thus either abandon the idea or try and find a free font, or a font that may be legally used for a fee, with characteristics sufficiently similar to the font that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Why not buy it? There are reputable sources where you can purchase a license to use this font as a web font.